# Is there a way to group controls in firefox extensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

I'm coming from the .net world so I know it can be done there, but I'm making a toolbar for firefox and I want it to show a set of controls (some kind of form) when I click one button and show another set when I click another button.

The question is whether there is an option to group some of the controls and hide them and then when the button is clicked I'll only have to change the visibility of the group or the other option which is to add these controls with javascript only after the button is clicked?

Again I know it can be done easily with .net but since I'm new to toolbar programming and didn't see anything related this on the web I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the basic principals are the same, you just need to add a "grouping" element around the set of controls you want to group. For a toolbar you could use a combination of a toolbaritem + vbox, and just new toolboxes inside it. And just use javascript to get the grouping element by id and hide/show it.

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<toolbox>
  <toolbar>
    <toolbaritem>
      <hbox id="tbgroup1" hidden="true">
        <toolbarbutton label="button"/>
        <toolbarbutton label="button"/>
        <toolbarbutton label="button"/>
      </hbox>
      <hbox id="tbgroup2">
        <toolbarbutton label="button"/>
        <toolbarbutton label="button"/>
        <toolbarbutton label="button"/>
      </hbox>
    </toolbaritem>
   </toolbox>
</window>
```

Comment: it looks like it is working although the skin of the vbox/hbox (I used hbox since this is what I needed and now it's working) doesn't look like the rest of the toolbar, do you know what should I do in regard to that tiny problem? thank you anyways.

Comment: Updated the example, the nested toolbox/toolbar nodes caused the styling to be overruled. You can safely remove it as in the example